# NodeJS + Passport-CAS Strategy: Logged out in other TAB of navigator and still logged-in

Tags: node.js, passport.js, cas

I have implemented CAS Strategy with passport-js in node-js. The login and log out works fine, when it's in the same tab of the navigator.

When I make login in my web and in other tab of the same navigator I make logout directly in CAS server, in my web appliction is still logged in. How can I do to logout my web in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It was a configuration issue of CAS server, it was blocking all communications in other ports than 80.
I have my webserver in port 8080, now I receive the POST logout from the CAS server and I can destroy sessions now in my webserver.